# Android : wait for Async ending in one fragment to launch another function in other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a Fragment Activity A, that implements two fragments B and C.
On a click of a button, I run a function in the fragment B, to refresh some data coming from internet. 
When the data is refreshed, I want to update my fragment C (which is a map), with the data I got from fragment B. The problem is that data refresh in fragment B is done through an async task

my code is like that in FragmentActivity A.

```
...
fragmentB.RefreshData();
Output output = fragmentB.getOutput();
fragmentC.RefreshData(output);
...
```

Because fragmentB executes an AsyncTask, when I'm doing .getOutput(), the code hasn't properly ended yet, therefore in my fragmentC I'm triggering a nullpointer exception.

My question is, how do I code so that I can wait for the end of the tasks in fragmentB before retrieving my output and pass it to fragmentC ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to implement a BroadcastReceiver in your fragment that will handle when the data is loaded or you could (not so good but simple) implement the onPostExecute on your task instantiation

Comment: I'll look into the first option... I think the second possibility would break the whole architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to GhostDerfel I did some research about the broadcasts, and here is the implemented solution.
I used LocalBroadcastManager as they are more secure for broadcasting if only done within your application.
For a great example on how to use them:
[how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

I put the receiver in my fragmentactivity A, to trigger the functions on fragment C
I put the sender in my fragment B, as soon as the onPostExecute happens

Thanks!